# Checking result before using $stmt -> fetch()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

probably a stupid question. I have the following code:

```
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo "<p><strong>" .$name. "</strong><br />" .$comment. "</p>";
}
```

I would like to execute the while ONLY if $stmt -> fetch() returns at least one row (this is a SELECT query).. but if I do

```
if ($stmt -> fetch())
```

It gets executed already one time, and I want to avoid this. Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you just want to check if the returned result exist or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Try using `$stmt->num_rows > 0`

```
$stmt->store_result();
if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 )
{
    while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        echo "<p><strong>" .$name. "</strong><br />" .$comment. "</p>";
    }
}
```

why `mysqli_result` has a `fetchAll` function and `mysqli_stmt` doesnt.... i have no idea.

---

Longer, but may work

```
$result = $stmt->fetch();
if( !empty( $result )
{
    do
    {
        echo "<p><strong>" .$name. "</strong><br />" .$comment. "</p>";
    } while( $result = $stmt->fetch() ); 
}
```

Comment: This always returns me 0!

Comment: and you've tested the prepared query?

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding $stmt -> store_result(); after $stmt -> bind_result; and before the IF. Why did I have to store the results to do it? Can you explain me? :)

Comment: im not sure, but i think Tanmay Majumder's answer may answer your question there....

Comment: yeah, added that into the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to query th db at-least one time to get count.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You are doing the correct check already, and the `do stuff` part will only occur if there is more than one result anyway. So you're already doing everything you need to do.

I.e. Your `echo` will only occur is `numRows` is greater than 0.

Comment: this doesnt allow you to do something if theres no rows though, if the OP was looking for that functionality

Comment: Very true, if that is his question, the `while` approach is still the best way. Followed outside of the loop by a numRows check

Answer (score -2):

`rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.

```
<?php
/* Delete all rows from the FRUIT table */
$stmt= $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM fruit');
$stmt->execute();

/* Return number of rows that were deleted */
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
print("Deleted $count rows.\n");
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
   Deleted 9 rows.
```

Comment: Sorry, but you confused the driver used. Which renders your answer misleading and wrong.